# cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'sslCertificateAlias'. No child element is expected at this point

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters

When I am enabling the SSL elements in adapter.xml. I am getting the error

cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'sslCertificateAlias'. No child element is   expected at this point.

Is there any way to resolve this?

My xml structure looks like this.

```
<displayName>Test525Adapter</displayName>
    <description>Test525Adapter</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <domain>docs.oracle.com</domain>
            <port>443</port>
        <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
            <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
            <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>
```

Comment: Is it really that difficult to mention the product version that you're using?

Comment: Sorry for that. I am using MobileFirst 7.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the order of the elements. Change it to the following and it should be OK:

```
<connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <domain>developer.ibm.com</domain>
            <port>443</port>
            <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <sslCertificateAlias>...</sslCertificateAlias> 
            <sslCertificatePassword>...</sslCertificatePassword>
            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
        </connectionPolicy>
```